# php form doesnt submit one of the fields

Tags: php, email, forms

i have bought a template that have built in contact form
problem is that it submits every thing except "company" name
i messed around with it but cant get to work it.
if you can point me to some solution i would be greatful

thanks in advance

this is php script

```
if(!$_POST) exit;

$email = $_POST['email'];


//$error[] = preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i', $_POST['email']) ? '' : 'INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS';
if(!eregi("^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*" ."@"."([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+"."\\.[a-z]{2,}"."$",$email )){
    $error.="Invalid email address entered";
    $errors=1;
}
if($errors==1) echo $error;
else{
    $values = array ('name','email','message');
    $required = array('name','email','message');

    $your_email = "--------@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "New Message: ".$_POST['subject'];
    $email_content = "new message:\n";

    foreach($values as $key => $value){
      if(in_array($value,$required)){
        if ($key != 'subject' && $key != 'company') {
          if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { echo 'Please fill in all required fields, marked with *'; exit; }
        }
        $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
      }
    }

    if(@mail($your_email,$email_subject,$email_content)) {
        echo 'Thanks for your message, will contact you soon.'; 
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$values = array ('name','email','message');
```

Add `'company'` to this list in the PHP script.

Also, I would modify the `foreach` loop to look like this, to get the intended functionality:

```
foreach($values as $key => $value)
{
    if(in_array($value,$required))
    {
        if(empty($_POST[$value]))
        {
                echo 'Please fill in all required fields, marked with *';
                exit;
        }
    }
    $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
}
```

This way, fields that aren't in the `$required` array are still added to the email if they exist - they just don't have to pass the empty check.

Comment: i tried but form will not send an email now

also adding to this array will make company a required field in form?

$required = array('name','email','message');

Comment: Then add it to $values only. That's the one that tells the script which fields need to be put into the email message (if the foreach loop).

Comment: @Marc B sorry this doesnt help, form will not submit filed

Comment: Then look at the javascript you had posted earlier. If the field/value makes it to the server, PHP can deal with it. It won't just selectively ignore one field because it doesn't like your cologne or whatever.

Comment: From the code posted, since the call to append the field to the email content array is inside an `if(in_array($value, $required))` block, it actually only includes the required fields in the email as coded. I thought it was odd.

Comment: @Marc B i have repoested javascript, it looks like it does get the fields through to php

Comment: @steve I've updated my answer to include a proper version of the foreach loop that should make it behave how one would normally expect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
$email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
```

Is never reached unless this line:

```
if (in_array($value,$required)) {
```

... is satisfied. This means, only fields listed in `$required` are going to be appended to the email. If that is OK, then simply change these lines:

```
$required = array('name','email','message');
$values = array ('name','email','message');
```

To read:

```
$required = array ('name','email','message','company');
$values = array ('name','email','message','company');
```

If that is NOT ok, change this:

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value,$required)) {
        if ($key != 'subject' && $key != 'company') {
            if (empty($_POST[$value])) {
                echo 'Please fill in all required fields, marked with *';
                exit;
            }
        }
        $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
    }
}
```

To look like this:

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value,$required)) {
        if ($key != 'subject' && $key != 'company') {
            if (empty($_POST[$value])) {
                echo 'Please fill in all required fields, marked with *';
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
    $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
}
```

Then you can take `company` out of `$required`, but leave it in `$values`. I suspect the template worked fine when you started because all fields were *required*.

If it *still* does not work,  please change this (up top):

```
if(!$_POST) exit;
```

To look like this:

```
if(!$_POST) exit;
print_r($_POST);
```

... and paste the additional output in your question.

Also, consider buying templates from another vendor :)